# Bootstrap menu collapse in ajax site. How can i close menu on every click?

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

my website uses Ajax and i want to close the Bootstrap's collapsed menu every time a user click click on every menu item, like this code. But this code doesn't work!! Damn!

```
$('.menu-item').click(function() {
$('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

How can I fix it?

(The code of menu is a simply bootstrap 3.0.0):

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

And the code of menu:

```
<div class="col-md-6 downmy">
<div class="navbar-collapse in" style="height: auto;">
<div class="menuTop"><ul id="menu-primary" class="nav nav-pills"><li id="menu-item-605" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-605"><a href="1.htm">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-314" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-314"><a href="2.htm">My Posts</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-315" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-315"><a href="3.htm">Guestbook</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When an element with class '.collapse' collapse or become visible the '.collapse' class will be replace by the `.in` class. So you will have to apply your hide on the `.in` class too.

```
$('.menu-item').click(function() {
    $('.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

Your menu items contain an anchor, when click this a new page will open... so i don't understand your question. To prevent this add an event.preventDefault (http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to your code:

```
$('.menu-item').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

$('.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bass, but your code only works in half.

My site uses ajax to the pages and then is called only the contents of the div "content" and the contents of the div "header" (where the menu) remains the same for every page that is loaded at the beginning.

Then the menu bootstrap works: the buttons appear, you close the menu when I click on one of the "menu-item", but it works only once, if I open the menu again then no longer works and only change pages on the site under , but the menu remains open.

I hope I have explained well.

How do I resolve?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand all. In your code you use: `class="navbar-collapse in"` for your menu. Cause this contains the class `.in` the page will open with the menu collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

The following query worked fine for me :

```
//The ":not('.dropdown-toggle')" is for the drop down menu (like a language menu) because 
//  I didn't want my navigation to close when clicking sub menu
$(".nav li a:not('.dropdown-toggle')").on('click',function(){
  $('.navbar-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

You can add it to your page or in the `$(document).ready(function(){/*...*/});` method