# Hide other accordion items

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I invoking an accordion item using a select `option` like http://jsfiddle.net/Rnfzz/1/

However,when i select an item from the select box,the other open accordion items are not automatically hidden.How can i hide the other accordion items such that only the clicked accordion item is shown?.

This is the html

C-1
            
          
        
        
          
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          
        
      
      
        
          
            
              C-2
            
          
        
        
          
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          
        
      
      
        
          
            
              C-3
            
          
        
        
          
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.

The jquery

```
$('.les_toggle').change(function(e){
if($(this).parents('.panel-group').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.in').collapse('hide');
}
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19460549/1596547

Comment: This doesn't work `$('.les_toggle').change(function(e){
    if($(this).parents('.panel-group').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){
        e.stopPropagation();
  $('.in').collapse('hide');
    }
 `

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way without the `e.stopPropagation()`

```
$('.les_toggle').on('change',function(){
    if($('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){ 
    $('.in').collapse('hide');
    }   
});
```

Thanks Bass Jobsen